# Grab data from password protected ASP website using Python's requests

Tags: python, asp.net, python-requests

I'm trying to get the whole content of a password-protected ASP site using Python's requests.

The programmer of the ASP Site told me that using PowerShell he is able to get the data using the following script:

```
$c = $host.UI.PromptForCredential('Your Credentials', 'Enter Credentials','','')
$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://server.com/app/login.aspx' -SessionVariable my_session
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.fields['xUsername']=$c.UserName
$form.fields['xPassword']=$c.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://server.com/app/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2Fapp%2FgetData.aspx%3Ftype%3DGETDATA%26id%3D123") -WebSession $my_session -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
```

I'm trying to achieve this using python's requests library, but does not seems to work properly. Instead of getting the data, I get the HTML code you'll normally see when trying to access without password.

```
import getpass
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user="my_username"
password=getpass.getpass()

data = {"xUsername":user, "xPassword": password}
with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get('https://server.com/app/login.aspx',verify=False).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    data["___VIEWSTATE"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    data["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    s.post('https://server.com/app/login.aspx', data=data)
    open_page = s.post(
        "https://server.com/app/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/app/getData.aspx?type=GETDATA&id=123")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to be making 3 HTTP requests in the python script, not 2 as in the original. The second request looks redundant as it doesn't match anything in the original, and the 3rd looks like it's missing the username and password data from the request body. I also don't know what all the guff about viewstate is meant to be about in the python script? How does that equate to the powershell? I know what ViewState is but based on the Powershell there's no indication that you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following problems:

1. Headers were missing, I simply went to the website using Chrome and get this information. In my case: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
2. All data found under "Form Data" **must be** included in the python request. Again, went to Chrome and logged in to the website normally. @Chrome: Inspect > Network > Search for login.asp > At the bottom I found "Form Data", which in my case looked like this (on parsed view):

   __EVENTTARGET:

   __EVENTARGUMENT:

   __VIEWSTATE:random long string

   __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:random hex number

   __EVENTVALIDATION:random long string

   xUsername:user

   xPassword:password

   btnLogin:Login

So, the correct python code looks like this:

```
import getpass
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user="my_username"
password=getpass.getpass()
url = "https://server.com/app/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fapp%2fgetData.aspx%3ftype%3dGETDATA%26id%3d123"
data = {"xUsername":user, "xPassword": password}
with requests.Session() as s:
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}
    r = s.get('https://server.com/app/login.aspx',verify=False,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    data["___VIEWSTATE"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    data["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    data["__EVENTTARGET"] = ""
    data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
    data["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]
    data["btnLogin"] = "Login"

    response = s.post(url,data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    print response.content
```

I must include the url in encoded form, or else I will get an error message from the server saying that one parameter is missing, i.e.:

```
url = "https://server.com/app/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/app/getData.aspx?type=GETDATA&id=123"
... SAME SCRIPT AS ABOVE ...
>>> print response.url
https://server.com/app/getData.aspx?type=GETUSER
>>> print response.content
ERROR   Some parameter is missing
```

Maybe someone knows a better approach for not having to decode the url.